# How to reactivate checking for Android Java in Eclipse on a particular file?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, lint

I had this problem once before and solved it but forgot how :(

Usually my Java files in Eclipse (Android Development Tool edition) are checked for syntax and compilation problems on the fly - I think Lint may be the tool, not sure - but I added one and mistakenly forgot to specify the .java extension at first.  Ever since, it doesn't get the automatic checking (only upon save).

All the other files are checked during on-the-fly editing, just not this particular one.  How to get it to be live-checked like the others?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There may be some setting in Eclipse somewhere, but I got tired of looking for it.  I made a copy of the source file (very important!), then deleted the original file from the project (and from disk).  Then I added it again, making sure to specify .java (not change it later), which made a blank file in the project.  Then I copied in the source I had saved from the first incarnation, and everything was happy again.

I guess if you add something like "ButtonMgr" to Eclipse, it understandably doesn't know what to do with it, and if you later rename it to "ButtonMgr.java", it doesn't automatically reset the dynamic syntax checking (only upon save) so the only way to pull it off is to save a copy, kill the original, make a new one and reincorporate the saved code.  If anyone else knows the "official" way, though, please post.